# How to add style to decoratedPopupPanel?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code that creates a decorated popup panel :

```
  ...
  var x = 600;
  var y = 150+row*23;
  var popPanel = app.createDecoratedPopupPanel().setStyleAttributes({background:'#FFFFDD',padding:'15px'}); 
  var message = app.createHTML("Opération non reversible !!<BR>Il faudra 'rafraichir' votre navigateur<BR>"+
  "après vous être effacé du planning (case ✖)<BR>pour voir les données à jour").setPixelSize(300,60).setStyleAttributes({background:'#FFFFDD',padding:'15px'}); 
  popPanel.add(message); 
  popPanel.setAnimationEnabled(true);
  popPanel.setPopupPosition(x, y);
  popPanel.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
  popPanel.show();// I didn't chain the commands to make it easier to test by commenting one or another...
return app;
}
```

and it gives this result :

[image]

**My question is :**  knowing that background attribute determines the surrounding zone (popup panel padding 15px) and that the inside widget has also its background color (and its own padding as well), **how can I change the color of this blue frame ?**

Comment: I too have wondered this (when working with decorated tab panels). I concluded that it was not possible. I used the Chrome inspector and found out that the blue part is actually a set of images. So it wouldn't be a simple CSS fix. I also found [this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/pGMGc7rC6QA) while looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't find that one... one of the answers (James Ferreira) brought me to the solution using `borderRadius`... so feel free to upgrade your comment to an answer so that I can accept it ;)  I'll post my new code as a second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that decorated** can not be redecorated in GAS. I too have wondered this (when working with decorated tab panels). I concluded that it was not possible. I used the Chrome inspector and found out that the blue part is actually a set of images. So it wouldn't be a simple CSS fix.

[This thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/pGMGc7rC6QA) seems to have the final verdict.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link from the other answer (leading to [James Ferreira's site](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/other-examples/gs-interactive)) I was able to build this new code that is a lot more easy to customize...

Here it is with the result below :

```
  ...
  var x = 600;
  var y = 150+row*23;
  var popPanel = app.createPopupPanel().setStyleAttributes({background:'#ccccaa',padding:'5px', borderRadius:'15px 15px 15px 15px',borderColor:'#ffffdd',borderWidth:'5px'}); 
  var message = app.createHTML("Opération non reversible !!<BR>Il faudra 'rafraichir' votre navigateur<BR>"+
  "après vous être effacé du planning (case ✖)<BR>pour voir les données à jour").setPixelSize(300,60).setStyleAttributes({padding:'5px'});  
  popPanel.add(message); popPanel.setAnimationEnabled(true).setPopupPosition(x, y).setAutoHideEnabled(true).show();
return app;
}
```

[image]

The `borderRadius:'px px px px'` can be used on any widget, allowing for nice buttons as wel ;-)

[image]

Comment: Don't forget about [browser support](http://caniuse.com/border-radius). Looks like everyone can do this except old versions of IE.

Comment: OK, but I have no way to test it on IE, I'm on Mac and Android, it works nicely on every Browsers I tested on both platforms...(Chrome, firefox, Safari and Android4 standard Browser) ...